# What is a constant vector?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, terminology

If the acceleration vector and velocity vector are antiparallel and constant vectors(?) what is the type of motion of the particle/body?
Also, what are constant vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is physics, such a question is best answered by a computation. Acceleration is the derivative of velocity:
$$\vec{a}=\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$$
If it's constant, then this can be be integrated as:
$$\vec{v}=\vec{a}t+\vec{v}_0$$
with $\vec{v}_0$ the initial velocity. Since you're asking for velocity to be also constant, then:
$$\vec{v}=\vec{v}_0$$
You can derive that to return to acceleration:
$$\vec{a}=\frac{d\vec{v}_0}{dt}=\vec{0}$$
So the only way to have constant acceleration *and* velocity is to have zero-acceleration, and constant (zero or non-zero) velocity.

Answer (score 1):

A constant vector has one direction and one magnitude,
if v and a are antiparallel, then  magnitude of v decreases till it is 0 and then increases,

Comment: v decreases till it becomes zero and then what increases?

Comment: @Karan - also $\rm v$, just in the other direction than before. $\rm v$ is the magnitude of the vector $\vec{\rm v}$ so for that it doesn't matter if $\rm v_x$ is positive or negative since you take the root of the square, which is positive.